# Stack Trace or Crashing point for Optional values when redirected to AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, option-type, lldb

I know this kind of question is kind of asked a lot but it's a bit different that i could not find elsewhere .

Age old **"Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"** we face everyday but usually it states to the point or line in the code where it is trying to unwrap an optional value and it is nil .

But in my case it is redirecting me to AppDelegate class due to which i don't know where it is exactly crashing .

Now my point is that is there any way to figure out which variable was being unwrapped that caused the crash.

The Debugger window does not state anything as well . Just the same Unwrapping optional- nil - failed statement

[image: App Delegate unwrapping failed]

[image: Debugger Area]

Following are the debugger commands that i used and their output after that :

> Blue - App name
>
> Red - Framework that we are using inside the app

```
di
```

[image: di debugger command]

```
thread backtrace
```

[image]

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint on it to hunt it down https://stackoverflow.com/a/35514845/3141234 I suspect it has to do with something crashing during the initialization of your VCs

Comment: Is is in Debug mode or it's a Release?

Comment: Can you type in lldb `di` upon the error and include the output?

Comment: @Alexander It's not working

Comment: @Kamil.S I did and there is bunch of text in the debugger . Will that provide anything ?

Comment: @user121095 yes please include the yielded output in your question.

Comment: Also `thread backtrace` please

Comment: @Kamil.S Please check the updated question

Comment: @user121095 it seems it fails in some asynchronously called Swift closure of the "red" framework. That's why you don't get a straightforward stacktrace. The `saveLocation` arg is a hint what kind of function/method it might be. I'd try commenting calls to "red" framework API one at a time trying to narrow it down. I assume you don't have the source code of the "red" framework, correct?.

Comment: @Kamil.S Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199684/discussion-between-user121095-and-kamil-s).